# Algorithm for total number of subsets of distinct elements in a given set of repetitive elements

Tags: algorithm, set

I have to find out the total number of subsets of 'k' (k > 1), length which contains distinct elements. Two subsets are considered different if there happened to be a same element but have different index. See the example below.

> Given a Set A={1, 1, 2, 3}.
>
> For k=2, the possible subsets are {1(index=1), 2}, {1(index=2), 2},
>   {1(index=1), 3}, {1(index=2), 3} and {2, 3}.  Total=5.
>
> For k=3,the possible subsets are {1(index=1), 2, 3}, {1(index=2), 2,
>   3}.  Total=2.
>
> For k=4,possible subsets=0.

I have to calculate this for an array of 10^5 length. Is there any combinatorial logic for it?

Comment: what about `k`? do you have restrictions? If you have something like `k < 1000` it would be nice.

Comment: k is the length of subsets. only restrictions is elements should be distinct and elements should be in increasing order.

Comment: so it can be as big as `n`?

Comment: k varies from 2 to anything less than or equal to n

Comment: I have a `O(n k)` algorithm at the moment but it seems it's won't work for the problem

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `O(m * k)` approach where `m` is the number of distinct elements in `A`.

Map every distinct element in `A` to its number of occurrences (you can use hash map for `O(n)` run-time). Let those numbers be

```
c[1], c[2], ..., c[m]
```

Now you can see that the total number of sets of `k` distinct is the sum of all possible products

```
c[i1] * c[i2] * ... * c[ik]
```

(in your example, `c[1] = 2, c[2] = 1, c[3] = 1` and you can see that the number of sets with 2 distinct elements is `2*1+1*1+2*1 = 5`).

You can also see that this number is the coefficient infront of `x^k` in the polynomial :

```
(1+c[1]*x)*(1+c[2]*x)*...*(1+c[m]*x)
```

This can be computed iteratively by multiplicatively updating a polynomial of degree `k`(at the beginning initialized to the constant `1`) with each of the polynomial `1 + c[i]* x`.

The run-time is `O(m * k)`.

Comment: @fjardon we want to calculate the total number of subset with a fixed size, and not for all sizes

Comment: this is the right idea for solving this problem since it gets all the possible multiplications.